# what is th proper way to refresh a full page on SAPUI5 (ESLINT:(sap-no-location-reload))?

Tags: javascript, sapui5, refresh, eslint, page-refresh

### Environment :

Framework : **SAPUI5**
Version : **1.65.6**
IDE : web-ide

### Problem :

My code works but according to the IDE maybe not in the proper way, Web-Ide return the error :

> location.reload() is not permitted. (sap-no-location-reload)
>    [ESLINT:
>   (sap-no-location-reload)]

### Code (minimal to reproduce):

the controller :

```
sap.ui.define([
    "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller",
    "sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel"
], function (Controller, JSONModel) {
    "use strict";

    return Controller.extend("namespace.controller.App", {
        onInit: function () {
            this.getView().setModel(new JSONModel({ 
                    actualizationDate: new Date()
                    }), "frontEnd");
        },
        onPressRefresh: function(){
            location.reload();
        }
    });
});
```

And the view :

```
<mvc:View 
    controllerName="namespace.controller.App" 
    xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
    xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
    xmlns="sap.m">
    <Shell id="shell">
        <App id="app">
            <pages>
                <Page id="page" title="{i18n>title}">
                    <content>
                        <Label text="{i18n>lastActualizedDateTime}" labelFor="lastActualizedTime" class="sapUiSmallMarginEnd"/>
                        <DateTimePicker 
                            id="lastActualizedTime" 
                            value="{path: 'frontEnd>/actualizationDate'}" 
                                    valueFormat="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" 
                                    displayFormat="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" 
                                    enabled="false"/>
                        <Button icon="sap-icon://refresh" type="Transparent" press="onPressRefresh"/>
                    </content>
                </Page>
            </pages>
        </App>
    </Shell>
</mvc:View>
```

For reproduce you can directly copy past the code in WebIde creating template from SAPUI5 Application.

### Remarks:

- I know the code work normally with `location.reload();`, I wish to know if their is a proper way to do the same in SAPUI5 (By proper way I mean not returning ESLINT error)
- `location.reload();` is in onPressRefresh on the controller, their is more code only for you to be able to reproduce the problem by a simple copy past in your web-ide

Comment: Do you need to reload the whole page? If you just want to reload data in your remote model there are ways to do so via the model

Comment: I need to reload the <Page> or even <content> element "only"

Comment: I'm still not sure what you exactly want to achieve. normally in onInit event you initialize everything. Mostly also getting data from the backend and creating models etc. So what about to execute onInit method or onPressRefresh : function() { this.onInit(); // and now some more things what you need to do }. thats the way how I'm doing it

Comment: @DubZ Actually not really to achieve, it more a curiosity if there was a proper way to do location.reload in UI5 framework :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reasoning behind this being in their linting is proper way to hard refresh is to not do it at all. If you want to ignore the error,

```
location.reload(); // eslint-disable-line sap-no-location-reload
```

However, if the only reason to refresh is to refresh the date, rewrite as follows:

```
    sap.ui.define([
        "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller",
        "sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel"
    ], function (Controller, JSONModel) {
        "use strict";

        return Controller.extend("namespace.controller.App", {
            onInit: function () {
                this.getView().setModel(new JSONModel({ 
                        actualizationDate: new Date()
                        }), "frontEnd");
            },
            onPressRefresh: function(){
                this.refreshDate();
            },
            refreshDate: function(){
                const oModel = this.getView().getModel("frontEnd");
                oModel.setProperty("/actualizationDate", new Date();
                oModel.updateBindings();
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply,on the minimal working example this is only with date but  I wish to reload most of the <content> of <Page> wich will be binding from model and backend

Comment: Why don't you just refresh the model then?

Answer (score 0):

The error free way is below if you want to reload the page in same place.

```
window.open(window.document.URL, "_self")
```